# the number of solutions ( algebraic structure )

Tags: linear-algebra

On $(-1,1)$ I have an algebraic structure $x*y=\frac{2xy+3(x+y)+2}{3xy+2(x+y)+3}, x,y\in (-1,1)$

At first exercise I found the identity element ( -2/3).At second exercise I found  that $f:(-1,1)\rightarrow (0,\infty ), f(x)=\frac{1-x}{5(1+x)}$ verifies $f(x*y)=f(x)\cdot f(y) \forall x,y\in (-1,1)$

I got stuck at the last exercise where I need to find the number of solutions of this equation: $x*x*x*...*x(ten \ times)=\frac{1}{10}$

I tried to use what I found at the second exercise: $f(x*x*x*...*x)=f(x)\cdot f(x)\cdot ...\cdot f(x)$ but I don't know how to continue.

Comment: Solve $f(x)^{10}=f(1/10)$ as $f(x)=f(1/10)^{1/10}$ and then $x=f^{-1}(f(1/10)^{1/10})$

Comment: I found that $(f(\frac{1}{10}))^{\frac{1}{10}}=\frac{9}{5\cdot 11}$ and $f^{-1}(x)=\frac{1-5x}{5x+1}$ so now I just replace x with what I found for $(f(\frac{1}{10}))^{\frac{1}{10}}$ ? Why $f(x)=f(1/10)^{1/10}$ which properties you used?

Comment: From $f(x)^{10}=f(1/10)$ to $f(x)=f(1/10)^{1/10}$ you only need that $f(x)$ is a real non-negative number, and that $f(1/10)$ is also real. On $(0,\infty)$ the function $x\mapsto x^{1/10}$ is the inverse of $x\mapsto x^{10}$.

Comment: Thank you for your help:)